# Make Particles follow a Black and White image texture

Tags: texturing, particles

I have a black and white image of some text. I would like to instantiate particles only on the black parts of the texture. I'm using the hair particle system and a rendering as object.
I have tried using [`Vertex Weight Edit Modifier`](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/modify/weight_edit.html) but it does not seem to work.
Any ideas on how to do this? Step by step instructions would be preferable as I'm new to Blender.

Comment: Many times a step by step instructions are available as tutorials at various places including the website that has a name that  rhymes with noonoob.

Comment: At the bottom of the particles pane do you see ... textures pane.  Create or refer to the texture starting there.  The you will need to switch to the texture and set its influence to [density] .

Comment: Particles can be influenced by a texture. Please show your UV map of you mesh even if it is a simple rectangle. – atomicbezierslinger 17 mins ago   Delete

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply.
It works fine but I couldn't figure out/ find out how to invert a texture in the texture panel.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In the image above on the middle see a particle system with an indication at the bottom that a texture is attached.  On the right side you see the location to change the texture and to specify its influence as density.  You press + New to create the texture reference you need. You can ignore the filler on the left side.  This writing is not a tutorial.  Please supplement this with a tutorial as specified above.  This is to show the primary panels to start your process.  You will replace the abstract texture with your texture.  Then if you prefer/need you can invert your texture in the texture panel or invert it before.  So you can flip the colors from black to white and white to black very easily. You can look at the headers of the panels and icons to navigate to the correct place.